1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract" in basic solidty contract testing
I am trying to test my solidity contract but it is not working. Please help.
/contracts/inbox.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

contract Inbox{
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory initialMessage){
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}

I am compiling the solidity contract using compile.js file
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    [inboxPath]: {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*'],
      },
    },
  },
};
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = {
  abi: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]['Inbox'].abi,
  bytecode: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]['Inbox'].evm.bytecode.object,
};

and reading the above bytecode inside the mocha test file
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { abi, bytecode } = require('../compile');
const { it } = require('mocha');

let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
  it('deploys a contract', () => {
    console.log(inbox);
  });
});

Kindly note, Both ABI and bytecode are not undefined, and I am getting value from them. I am also getting eth accounts also. But don't know why below error is showing.
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)


  Inbox
eth_accounts
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


  0 passing (27ms)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/inbox.test.js:13:44)

I have also checked my package.json for compiler version but both are same.
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache": "^7.9.2",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.26",
    "web3": "^4.9.0" 
  }
}


Try the following code:
const path = require('path'); const fs = require('fs'); const solc =
require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'UTF-8');

const input = {   language: 'Solidity',   sources: {
    'inbox.sol': {
      content: source,
    },   },   settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*'],
      },
    },   }, };

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = {   abi:
output.contracts['inbox.sol']['Inbox'].abi,   bytecode:
output.contracts['inbox.sol']['Inbox'].evm.bytecode.object, };

